# No such file or directory Terminal

Tags: path, terminal, bin

I am trying to understand the logic of the PATH directory and have been going through the threads here. I basically installed node onto my machine but for some reason Terminal cannot find via cd node:

```
MACHINE:~ KEN$ cd node
-bash: cd: node: No such file or directory
```

I have listed the contents of my bin directory (which it can find) and it it is clearly there:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/
git             git-receive-pack    git-upload-pack   npm
git-credential-osxkeychain  git-shell       github
git-cvsserver       git-upload-archive  node
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin` output?

Comment: And what does `cd /usr/local/bin/node` output?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `PATH` does - it's just a list of directories to search for executables - you can't use it as a shortcut when you `cd` or `ls`.

Comment: Hi Tripp. The first `ls -l /usr/local/bin` question answers as follows:`-rwxr-xr-x  1 24561  wheel  20036016  2 May 01:59 node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel        38 28 May 14:33 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

Comment: Second question answer: `cd /usr/local/bin/node
-bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/node: Not a directory`

Answer (score 1):

Is `node` a directory? You can only use the `cd` command to open a directory.

Try:

`cd /usr/local/bin/`

`ls`

and see what it shows. Normally the directories are blue listed

Comment: Hi Fabio node is a directoryas you can see from above I cannot cd into it, when I ls I get `ls /usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node`. I just want to be "inside" that directory like I can be with bin